# Reading data from kinesis stream unsuccessfully

Tags: stream, aws-sdk, indexoutofboundsexception, amazon-kinesis

I am working with Amazon Kinesis data streams. My Kinesis stream consists of only one shard.
I am trying to read data (records) from the stream after writing some data (records) to the same stream. My records are simple JSON's. 
I can see through the Amazon console the readings and the writings.
When I try to print the content of the record with "record.getData()" I got this error :

```
java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=4 lim=4 cap=4]
20:35:59.118 [RecordProcessor-0000] WARN com.kinesisconsumer.AmazonKinesisApplicationSampleRecordProcessor - Caught throwable while processing record UserRecord [subSequenceNumber=0, explicitHashKey=null, aggregated=false, getSequenceNumber()=49593662497507120518174908605360552573875197411355262978, getData()=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=4 lim=4 cap=4], getPartitionKey()=12345]
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -9
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1931)
    at com.kinesisconsumer.AmazonKinesisApplicationSampleRecordProcessor.processSingleRecord(AmazonKinesisApplicationSampleRecordProcessor.java:112)
    at com.kinesisconsumer.AmazonKinesisApplicationSampleRecordProcessor.processRecordsWithRetries(AmazonKinesisApplicationSampleRecordProcessor.java:75)
    at com.kinesisconsumer.AmazonKinesisApplicationSampleRecordProcessor.processRecords(AmazonKinesisApplicationSampleRecordProcessor.java:53)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.V1ToV2RecordProcessorAdapter.processRecords(V1ToV2RecordProcessorAdapter.java:42)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.ProcessTask.callProcessRecords(ProcessTask.java:221)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.ProcessTask.call(ProcessTask.java:176)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.call(MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.java:49)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.call(MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.java:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Here is my code :

```
public class AmazonKinesisApplicationRecordProcessorFactory implements IRecordProcessorFactory {
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public IRecordProcessor createProcessor() {
        return new AmazonKinesisApplicationSampleRecordProcessor();
    }
}
```

---

```
public final class AmazonKinesisApplicationSample {

   public static final String SAMPLE_APPLICATION_STREAM_NAME = "LimorKinesis";

    private static final String SAMPLE_APPLICATION_NAME = "SampleKinesisApplication";

    // Initial position in the stream when the application starts up for the first time.
    // Position can be one of LATEST (most recent data) or TRIM_HORIZON (oldest available data)
    private static final InitialPositionInStream SAMPLE_APPLICATION_INITIAL_POSITION_IN_STREAM =
            InitialPositionInStream.LATEST;

    private static ProfileCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider;

    private static void init() {
        // Ensure the JVM will refresh the cached IP values of AWS resources (e.g. service endpoints).
        java.security.Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl", "60");

        /*
         * The ProfileCredentialsProvider will return your [default]
         * credential profile by reading from the credentials file located at
         * (~/.aws/credentials).
         */
        credentialsProvider = new ProfileCredentialsProvider();
        try {
            credentialsProvider.getCredentials();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AmazonClientException("Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file. "
                    + "Please make sure that your credentials file is at the correct "
                    + "location (~/.aws/credentials), and is in valid format.", e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        init();

        if (args.length == 1 && "delete-resources".equals(args[0])) {
            deleteResources();
            return;
        }

        String workerId = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName() + ":" + UUID.randomUUID();
        KinesisClientLibConfiguration kinesisClientLibConfiguration =
                new KinesisClientLibConfiguration(SAMPLE_APPLICATION_NAME,
                        SAMPLE_APPLICATION_STREAM_NAME,
                        credentialsProvider,
                        workerId);
        kinesisClientLibConfiguration.withInitialPositionInStream(SAMPLE_APPLICATION_INITIAL_POSITION_IN_STREAM);
        kinesisClientLibConfiguration.withRegionName("us-west-2");//todo : added region west-2

        IRecordProcessorFactory recordProcessorFactory = new AmazonKinesisApplicationRecordProcessorFactory();
        Worker worker = new Worker(recordProcessorFactory, kinesisClientLibConfiguration);

        System.out.printf("Running %s to process stream %s as worker %s...\n",
                SAMPLE_APPLICATION_NAME,
                SAMPLE_APPLICATION_STREAM_NAME,
                workerId);

        int exitCode = 0;
        try {
            worker.run();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            System.err.println("Caught throwable while processing data.");
            t.printStackTrace();
            exitCode = 1;
        }
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }

    public static void deleteResources() {
        // Delete the stream
        AmazonKinesis kinesis = AmazonKinesisClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
                .withRegion("us-west-2")
                .build();

        System.out.printf("Deleting the Amazon Kinesis stream used by the sample. Stream Name = %s.\n",
                SAMPLE_APPLICATION_STREAM_NAME);
        try {
            kinesis.deleteStream(SAMPLE_APPLICATION_STREAM_NAME);
        } catch (ResourceNotFoundException ex) {
            // The stream doesn't exist.
        }

        // Delete the table
        AmazonDynamoDB dynamoDB = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
                .withRegion("us-west-2")
                .build();
        System.out.printf("Deleting the Amazon DynamoDB table used by the Amazon Kinesis Client Library. Table Name = %s.\n",
                SAMPLE_APPLICATION_NAME);
        try {
            dynamoDB.deleteTable(SAMPLE_APPLICATION_NAME);
        } catch (com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ResourceNotFoundException ex) {
            // The table doesn't exist.
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class AmazonKinesisApplicationSampleRecordProcessor implements IRecordProcessor {

    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(AmazonKinesisApplicationSampleRecordProcessor.class);
    private String kinesisShardId;

    // Backoff and retry settings
    private static final long BACKOFF_TIME_IN_MILLIS = 3000L;
    private static final int NUM_RETRIES = 10;

    // Checkpoint about once a minute
    private static final long CHECKPOINT_INTERVAL_MILLIS = 60000L;
    private long nextCheckpointTimeInMillis;

    private final CharsetDecoder decoder = Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder();

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(String shardId) {
        LOG.info("Initializing record processor for shard: " + shardId);
        this.kinesisShardId = shardId;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void processRecords(List<Record> records, IRecordProcessorCheckpointer checkpointer) {
        LOG.info("Processing " + records.size() + " records from " + kinesisShardId);

        // Process records and perform all exception handling.
        processRecordsWithRetries(records);

        // Checkpoint once every checkpoint interval.
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() > nextCheckpointTimeInMillis) {
            checkpoint(checkpointer);
            nextCheckpointTimeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() + CHECKPOINT_INTERVAL_MILLIS;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Process records performing retries as needed. Skip "poison pill" records.
     *
     * @param records Data records to be processed.
     */
    private void processRecordsWithRetries(List<Record> records) {
        for (Record record : records) {
            boolean processedSuccessfully = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_RETRIES; i++) {
                try {
                    //
                    // Logic to process record goes here.
                    //
                    processSingleRecord(record);

                    processedSuccessfully = true;
                    break;
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    LOG.warn("Caught throwable while processing record " + record, t);
                }

                // backoff if we encounter an exception.
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(BACKOFF_TIME_IN_MILLIS);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    LOG.debug("Interrupted sleep", e);
                }
            }

            if (!processedSuccessfully) {
                LOG.error("Couldn't process record " + record + ". Skipping the record.");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Process a single record.
     *
     * @param record The record to be processed.
     */
    private void processSingleRecord(Record record) {
        System.out.println(record.getData());

        String data = null;
        try {
            // For this app, we interpret the payload as UTF-8 chars.
            data = decoder.decode(record.getData()).toString();
            // Assume this record came from AmazonKinesisSample and log its age.
            long recordCreateTime = new Long(data.substring("testData-".length()));
            long ageOfRecordInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() - recordCreateTime;

            LOG.info(record.getSequenceNumber() + ", " + record.getPartitionKey() + ", " + data + ", Created "
                    + ageOfRecordInMillis + " milliseconds ago.");
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            LOG.info("Record does not match sample record format. Ignoring record with data; " + data);
        } catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
            LOG.error("Malformed data: " + data, e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void shutdown(IRecordProcessorCheckpointer checkpointer, ShutdownReason reason) {
        LOG.info("Shutting down record processor for shard: " + kinesisShardId);
        // Important to checkpoint after reaching end of shard, so we can start processing data from child shards.
        if (reason == ShutdownReason.TERMINATE) {
            checkpoint(checkpointer);
        }
    }

    /** Checkpoint with retries.
     * @param checkpointer
     */
    private void checkpoint(IRecordProcessorCheckpointer checkpointer) {
        LOG.info("Checkpointing shard " + kinesisShardId);
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_RETRIES; i++) {
            try {
                checkpointer.checkpoint();
                break;
            } catch (ShutdownException se) {
                // Ignore checkpoint if the processor instance has been shutdown (fail over).
                LOG.info("Caught shutdown exception, skipping checkpoint.", se);
                break;
            } catch (ThrottlingException e) {
                // Backoff and re-attempt checkpoint upon transient failures
                if (i >= (NUM_RETRIES - 1)) {
                    LOG.error("Checkpoint failed after " + (i + 1) + "attempts.", e);
                    break;
                } else {
                    LOG.info("Transient issue when checkpointing - attempt " + (i + 1) + " of "
                            + NUM_RETRIES, e);
                }
            } catch (InvalidStateException e) {
                // This indicates an issue with the DynamoDB table (check for table, provisioned IOPS).
                LOG.error("Cannot save checkpoint to the DynamoDB table used by the Amazon Kinesis Client Library.", e);
                break;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(BACKOFF_TIME_IN_MILLIS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                LOG.debug("Interrupted sleep", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class AmazonKinesisRecordProducerSample {

    private static AmazonKinesis kinesis;

    private static void init() throws Exception {
        /*
         * The ProfileCredentialsProvider will return your [default]
         * credential profile by reading from the credentials file located at
         * (~/.aws/credentials).
         */
        ProfileCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new ProfileCredentialsProvider();
        try {
            credentialsProvider.getCredentials();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AmazonClientException(
                    "Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file. " +
                            "Please make sure that your credentials file is at the correct " +
                            "location (~/.aws/credentials), and is in valid format.",
                    e);
        }

        kinesis = AmazonKinesisClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
                .withRegion("us-west-2")
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        init();

        final String myStreamName = AmazonKinesisApplicationSample.SAMPLE_APPLICATION_STREAM_NAME;
        final Integer myStreamSize = 1;

        // Describe the stream and check if it exists.
        DescribeStreamRequest describeStreamRequest = new DescribeStreamRequest().withStreamName(myStreamName);
        try {
            StreamDescription streamDescription = kinesis.describeStream(describeStreamRequest).getStreamDescription();
            System.out.printf("Stream %s has a status of %s.\n", myStreamName, streamDescription.getStreamStatus());

            if ("DELETING".equals(streamDescription.getStreamStatus())) {
                System.out.println("Stream is being deleted. This sample will now exit.");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            // Wait for the stream to become active if it is not yet ACTIVE.
            if (!"ACTIVE".equals(streamDescription.getStreamStatus())) {
                waitForStreamToBecomeAvailable(myStreamName);
            }
        } catch (ResourceNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.printf("Stream %s does not exist. Creating it now.\n", myStreamName);

            // Create a stream. The number of shards determines the provisioned throughput.
            CreateStreamRequest createStreamRequest = new CreateStreamRequest();
            createStreamRequest.setStreamName(myStreamName);
            createStreamRequest.setShardCount(myStreamSize);
            kinesis.createStream(createStreamRequest);
            // The stream is now being created. Wait for it to become active.
            waitForStreamToBecomeAvailable(myStreamName);
        }

        // List all of my streams.
        ListStreamsRequest listStreamsRequest = new ListStreamsRequest();
        listStreamsRequest.setLimit(10);
        ListStreamsResult listStreamsResult = kinesis.listStreams(listStreamsRequest);
        List<String> streamNames = listStreamsResult.getStreamNames();
        while (listStreamsResult.isHasMoreStreams()) {
            if (streamNames.size() > 0) {
                listStreamsRequest.setExclusiveStartStreamName(streamNames.get(streamNames.size() - 1));
            }

            listStreamsResult = kinesis.listStreams(listStreamsRequest);
            streamNames.addAll(listStreamsResult.getStreamNames());
        }
        // Print all of my streams.
        System.out.println("List of my streams: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < streamNames.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("\t- " + streamNames.get(i));
        }

        System.out.printf("Putting records in stream : %s until this application is stopped...\n", myStreamName);
        System.out.println("Press CTRL-C to stop.");
        // Write records to the stream until this program is aborted.
        while (true) {
            long createTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            PutRecordRequest putRecordRequest = new PutRecordRequest();
            putRecordRequest.setStreamName(myStreamName);
            putRecordRequest.setData(ByteBuffer.wrap(String.format("testData-%d", createTime).getBytes()));
            putRecordRequest.setPartitionKey(String.format("partitionKey-%d", createTime));
            PutRecordResult putRecordResult = kinesis.putRecord(putRecordRequest);
            System.out.printf("Successfully put record, partition key : %s, ShardID : %s, SequenceNumber : %s.\n",
                    putRecordRequest.getPartitionKey(),
                    putRecordResult.getShardId(),
                    putRecordResult.getSequenceNumber());
        }
    }

    private static void waitForStreamToBecomeAvailable(String myStreamName) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.printf("Waiting for %s to become ACTIVE...\n", myStreamName);

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long endTime = startTime + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(10);
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) {
            Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(20));

            try {
                DescribeStreamRequest describeStreamRequest = new DescribeStreamRequest();
                describeStreamRequest.setStreamName(myStreamName);
                // ask for no more than 10 shards at a time -- this is an optional parameter
                describeStreamRequest.setLimit(10);
                DescribeStreamResult describeStreamResponse = kinesis.describeStream(describeStreamRequest);

                String streamStatus = describeStreamResponse.getStreamDescription().getStreamStatus();
                System.out.printf("\t- current state: %s\n", streamStatus);
                if ("ACTIVE".equals(streamStatus)) {
                    return;
                }
            } catch (ResourceNotFoundException ex) {
                // ResourceNotFound means the stream doesn't exist yet,
                // so ignore this error and just keep polling.
            } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
                throw ase;
            }
        }

        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Stream %s never became active", myStreamName));
    }
}
```

---

I used the sample code from this link : 
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/tree/master/src/samples/AmazonKinesis

Comment: You can catch ThrottlingException, wait for a few seconds and retry by calling the same function for x number of reattempts.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change **Application Name** and then retry. Most of problems gets resolved by this simple change.

or try this code below.

AmazonKinesisApplicationSample.java :-

```
package KinesiSampleApplication.www.intellyzen.com;
/*
 * Copyright 2012-2019 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License").
 * You may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * A copy of the License is located at
 *
 *  http://aws.amazon.com/apache2.0
 *
 * or in the "license" file accompanying this file. This file is distributed
 * on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either
 * express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing
 * permissions and limitations under the License.
 */

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.UUID;

import com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesis;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.interfaces.IRecordProcessorFactory;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.InitialPositionInStream;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.KinesisClientLibConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.Worker;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.ResourceNotFoundException;

/**
 * Sample Amazon Kinesis Application.
 */
public final class AmazonKinesisApplicationSample {

    /*
     * Before running the code:
     *      Fill in your AWS access credentials in the provided credentials
     *      file template, and be sure to move the file to the default location
     *      (~/.aws/credentials) where the sample code will load the
     *      credentials from.
     *      https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#security_credential
     *
     * WARNING:
     *      To avoid accidental leakage of your credentials, DO NOT keep
     *      the credentials file in your source directory.
     */

    public static final String SAMPLE_APPLICATION_STREAM_NAME = "IOTREST-API";

    private static final String SAMPLE_APPLICATION_NAME = "SampleKinesisApplicationadsfdsa11    ";

    // Initial position in the stream when the application starts up for the first time.
    // Position can be one of LATEST (most recent data) or TRIM_HORIZON (oldest available data)
    private static final InitialPositionInStream SAMPLE_APPLICATION_INITIAL_POSITION_IN_STREAM =
            InitialPositionInStream.LATEST;

    private static ProfileCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider;

    private static void init() {
        // Ensure the JVM will refresh the cached IP values of AWS resources (e.g. service endpoints).
        java.security.Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl", "60");

        /*
         * The ProfileCredentialsProvider will return your [default]
         * credential profile by reading from the credentials file located at
         * (~/.aws/credentials).
         */
        credentialsProvider = new ProfileCredentialsProvider();
        try {
            credentialsProvider.getCredentials();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AmazonClientException("Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file. "
                    + "Please make sure that your credentials file is at the correct "
                    + "location (~/.aws/credentials), and is in valid format.", e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        init();

        if (args.length == 1 && "delete-resources".equals(args[0])) {
            deleteResources();
            return;
        }

        String workerId = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName() + ":" + UUID.randomUUID();
        KinesisClientLibConfiguration kinesisClientLibConfiguration =
                new KinesisClientLibConfiguration(SAMPLE_APPLICATION_NAME,
                        SAMPLE_APPLICATION_STREAM_NAME,
                        credentialsProvider,
                        workerId);
        kinesisClientLibConfiguration.withInitialPositionInStream(SAMPLE_APPLICATION_INITIAL_POSITION_IN_STREAM);

        IRecordProcessorFactory recordProcessorFactory = new AmazonKinesisApplicationRecordProcessorFactory();
        Worker worker = new Worker(recordProcessorFactory, kinesisClientLibConfiguration);

        System.out.printf("Running %s to process stream %s as worker %s...\n",
                SAMPLE_APPLICATION_NAME,
                SAMPLE_APPLICATION_STREAM_NAME,
                workerId);

        int exitCode = 0;
        try {
            worker.run();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            System.err.println("Caught throwable while processing data.");
            t.printStackTrace();
            exitCode = 1;
        }
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }

    public static void deleteResources() {
        // Delete the stream
        AmazonKinesis kinesis = AmazonKinesisClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
            .withRegion("us-east-1")
            .build();

        System.out.printf("Deleting the Amazon Kinesis stream used by the sample. Stream Name = %s.\n",
                SAMPLE_APPLICATION_STREAM_NAME);
        try {
            kinesis.deleteStream(SAMPLE_APPLICATION_STREAM_NAME);
        } catch (ResourceNotFoundException ex) {
            // The stream doesn't exist.
        }

        // Delete the table
        AmazonDynamoDB dynamoDB = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
            .withRegion("us-east-1")
            .build();
        System.out.printf("Deleting the Amazon DynamoDB table used by the Amazon Kinesis Client Library. Table Name = %s.\n",
                SAMPLE_APPLICATION_NAME);
        try {
            dynamoDB.deleteTable(SAMPLE_APPLICATION_NAME);
        } catch (com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ResourceNotFoundException ex) {
            // The table doesn't exist.
        }
    }
}
```

AmazonKinesisApplicationSampleRecordProcessor.java:-

```
package KinesiSampleApplication.www.intellyzen.com;

/*
 * Copyright 2012-2016 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License").
 * You may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * A copy of the License is located at
 *
 *  http://aws.amazon.com/apache2.0
 *
 * or in the "license" file accompanying this file. This file is distributed
 * on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either
 * express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing
 * permissions and limitations under the License.
 */

import java.nio.charset.CharacterCodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.exceptions.InvalidStateException;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.exceptions.ShutdownException;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.exceptions.ThrottlingException;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.interfaces.IRecordProcessor;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.interfaces.IRecordProcessorCheckpointer;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.Record;

import software.amazon.kinesis.lifecycle.ShutdownReason;

/**
 * Processes records and checkpoints progress.
 */
public class AmazonKinesisApplicationSampleRecordProcessor implements IRecordProcessor {

    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(AmazonKinesisApplicationSampleRecordProcessor.class);
    private String kinesisShardId;

    // Backoff and retry settings
    private static final long BACKOFF_TIME_IN_MILLIS = 3000L;
    private static final int NUM_RETRIES = 10;

    // Checkpoint about once a minute
    private static final long CHECKPOINT_INTERVAL_MILLIS = 60000L;
    private long nextCheckpointTimeInMillis;

    private final CharsetDecoder decoder = Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder();

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public void initialize(String shardId) {
        LOG.info("Initializing record processor for shard: " + shardId);
        this.kinesisShardId = shardId;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public void processRecords(List<Record> records, IRecordProcessorCheckpointer checkpointer) {
        LOG.info("Processing " + records.size() + " records from " + kinesisShardId);

        // Process records and perform all exception handling.
        processRecordsWithRetries(records);

        // Checkpoint once every checkpoint interval.
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() > nextCheckpointTimeInMillis) {
            checkpoint(checkpointer);
            nextCheckpointTimeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() + CHECKPOINT_INTERVAL_MILLIS;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Process records performing retries as needed. Skip "poison pill" records.
     * 
     * @param records Data records to be processed.
     */
    private void processRecordsWithRetries(List<Record> records) {
        for (Record record : records) {
            boolean processedSuccessfully = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_RETRIES; i++) {
                try {
                    //
                    // Logic to process record goes here.
                    //
                    processSingleRecord(record);

                    processedSuccessfully = true;
                    break;
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    LOG.warn("Caught throwable while processing record " + record, t);
                }

                // backoff if we encounter an exception.
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(BACKOFF_TIME_IN_MILLIS);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    LOG.debug("Interrupted sleep", e);
                }
            }

            if (!processedSuccessfully) {
                LOG.error("Couldn't process record " + record + ". Skipping the record.");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Process a single record.
     * 
     * @param record The record to be processed.
     */
    private void processSingleRecord(Record record) {
        // TODO Add your own record processing logic here

        String data = null;
        try {
            // For this app, we interpret the payload as UTF-8 chars.
            data = decoder.decode(record.getData()).toString();
            System.out.println(data);
            System.out.println("\n");
            // Assume this record came from AmazonKinesisSample and log its age.
            long recordCreateTime = new Long(data.substring("testData-".length()));
            long ageOfRecordInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() - recordCreateTime;
            LOG.info(record.getSequenceNumber() + ", " + record.getPartitionKey() + ", " + data + ", Created "
                    + ageOfRecordInMillis + " milliseconds ago.");
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
           LOG.info("Record does not match sample record format. Ignoring record with data; " + data);}
        catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
            LOG.error("Malformed data: " + data, e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public void shutdown(IRecordProcessorCheckpointer checkpointer, ShutdownReason reason) {
        LOG.info("Shutting down record processor for shard: " + kinesisShardId);
        // Important to checkpoint after reaching end of shard, so we can start processing data from child shards.
        if (reason == ShutdownReason.LEASE_LOST) {
            checkpoint(checkpointer);
        }
    }

    /** Checkpoint with retries.
     * @param checkpointer
     */
    private void checkpoint(IRecordProcessorCheckpointer checkpointer) {
        LOG.info("Checkpointing shard " + kinesisShardId);
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_RETRIES; i++) {
            try {
                checkpointer.checkpoint();
                break;
            } catch (ShutdownException se) {
                // Ignore checkpoint if the processor instance has been shutdown (fail over).
                LOG.info("Caught shutdown exception, skipping checkpoint.", se);
                break;
            } catch (ThrottlingException e) {
                // Backoff and re-attempt checkpoint upon transient failures
                if (i >= (NUM_RETRIES - 1)) {
                    LOG.error("Checkpoint failed after " + (i + 1) + "attempts.", e);
                    break;
                } else {
                    LOG.info("Transient issue when checkpointing - attempt " + (i + 1) + " of "
                            + NUM_RETRIES, e);
                }
            } catch (InvalidStateException e) {
                // This indicates an issue with the DynamoDB table (check for table, provisioned IOPS).
                LOG.error("Cannot save checkpoint to the DynamoDB table used by the Amazon Kinesis Client Library.", e);
                break;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(BACKOFF_TIME_IN_MILLIS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                LOG.debug("Interrupted sleep", e);
            }
        }
    }

    public void shutdown(IRecordProcessorCheckpointer checkpointer,
            com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.ShutdownReason reason) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

AmazonKinesisApplicationRecordProcessorFactory.java:-

```
package KinesiSampleApplication.www.intellyzen.com;

/*
 * Copyright 2012-2016 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License").
 * You may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * A copy of the License is located at
 *
 *  http://aws.amazon.com/apache2.0
 *
 * or in the "license" file accompanying this file. This file is distributed
 * on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either
 * express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing
 * permissions and limitations under the License.
 */

import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.interfaces.IRecordProcessor;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.interfaces.IRecordProcessorFactory;

/**
 * Used to create new record processors.
 */
public class AmazonKinesisApplicationRecordProcessorFactory implements IRecordProcessorFactory {
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public IRecordProcessor createProcessor() {
        return new AmazonKinesisApplicationSampleRecordProcessor();
    }
}
```

pom.xml:-

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>KinesiSampleApplication</groupId>
  <artifactId>www.intellyzen.com</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>www.intellyzen.com</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>software.amazon.kinesis</groupId>
    <artifactId>amazon-kinesis-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-kinesis</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.551</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/amazon-kinesis-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>amazon-kinesis-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>software.amazon.kinesis</groupId>
    <artifactId>amazon-kinesis-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Thanks for using https://jar-download.com -->

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-cbor -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-cbor</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use case -- "I am trying to read data (records) from the stream"

You can find all AWS Java V2 examples here: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/example_code/kinesis

Here is the Solution using the AWS Kinesis Java v2 API...

```
package com.example.kinesis;

//snippet-start:[kinesis.java2.getrecord.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.SdkBytes;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.KinesisClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.model.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
//snippet-end:[kinesis.java2.getrecord.import]

/**
 * Demonstrates how to read data from a Kinesis Data Stream. Before running this Java code example, populate a Data Stream
 * by running the StockTradesWriter example. That example populates a Data Stream that you can then use for this example.
 */

public class GetRecords {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // snippet-start:[kinesis.java2.getrecord.main]
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        KinesisClient kinesisClient = KinesisClient.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        getStockTrades(kinesisClient);
    }

    private static void getStockTrades(KinesisClient kinesisClient) {

            String shardIterator;
            String lastShardId = null;

            // Retrieve the Shards from a Stream
            DescribeStreamRequest describeStreamRequest = DescribeStreamRequest.builder()
                    .streamName("StockTrade")
                    .build();
            List<Shard> shards = new ArrayList<>();

            DescribeStreamResponse streamRes;
            do {
               // describeStreamRequest.exclusiveStartShardId(lastShardId);
                streamRes = kinesisClient.describeStream(describeStreamRequest);
                shards.addAll(streamRes.streamDescription().shards());

                if (shards.size() > 0) {
                    lastShardId = shards.get(shards.size() - 1).shardId();
                }
            } while (streamRes.streamDescription().hasMoreShards());

            GetShardIteratorRequest itReq = GetShardIteratorRequest.builder()
                    .streamName("StockTrade")
                    .shardIteratorType("TRIM_HORIZON")
                    .shardId(shards.get(0).shardId())
                    .build();

            GetShardIteratorResponse shardIteratorResult = kinesisClient.getShardIterator(itReq);
            shardIterator = shardIteratorResult.shardIterator();

            // Continuously read data records from shard.
            List<Record> records;
            while (true) {
                // Create new GetRecordsRequest with existing shardIterator.
                // Set maximum records to return to 1000.
                GetRecordsRequest recordsRequest = GetRecordsRequest.builder()
                        .shardIterator(shardIterator)
                        .limit(1000)
                        .build();

                GetRecordsResponse result = kinesisClient.getRecords(recordsRequest);

                // Put result into record list. Result may be empty.
                records = result.records();

                // Print records
                for (Record record : records) {
                    SdkBytes byteBuffer = record.data();
                    System.out.println(String.format("Seq No: %s - %s", record.sequenceNumber(),
                            new String(byteBuffer.asByteArray())));
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(exception);
                }

                shardIterator = result.nextShardIterator();
             }
        // snippet-end:[kinesis.java2.getrecord.main]
        }
}
```